# Problem setting onChildClickListener for an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, onclick, expandablelistview

I am having a problem getting my click listener for the expandable list view to work. Am I implementing this correctly?

Code:

```
elv = getExpandableListView();

// Set up the adapter
mAdapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter();
elv.setAdapter(mAdapter);

elv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            v.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: At first I thought the click wasn't being recognized, but it is. It's just that the background color won't change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't called show() on your Toast message. So, if you're determining if it worked merely on the Toast message, it won't seem to be working. Add .show(); at the end of the line where you create the toast and it should show up

Comment: D'oh. Well, it's recognizing the click - but it still won't change the color. Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the color to one of the constant values in the Color class. so v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

Comment: That was pretty obvious. Does affixing 0x before a hex value not work? I thought the way to use a hex value was setBackgroundColor(0xF1F1F1)?

Comment: Also, thank you. You've saved me lots of trouble and agonizing over this.

Comment: If you want to enter a custom value do setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fff1f1f1"));  the leading FF is the color's alpha.. these can be omitted if you want